# Numpy sum rows ... getting strange results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to take a bunch of rows of effectively binary data, rows of 0s and 1s, and sum them. It's an array of around a million records loaded from text using numpy.loadtxt.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
sdata = np.asfarray(np.sum(data,axis=1))
```

Problem is I'm getting nonsense results, I'm getting an array full of effectively what amounts to line numbers or something. I can print out an array and for instance the first three lines are [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. But the first three "sums" in the sdata array read 0.0000000e+00, 1.000000e+01, 2.00000e+01. Which is clearly not the sums I'm looking for.

If I use axis=0 I get sums of columns as I would expect, so I'm not sure what to do about this...any advice would be super. Thanks!

I'm using usecols=range(1,n) where I've already checked (and used) the length of lines previously. Here's a sample of the text file as requested.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
30 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
60 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
70 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
90 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
110 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
120 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
130 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
140 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
150 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
160 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
170 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
180 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
190 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

To me it looks suspiciously like it's using that first column to make the sums, however if I get it to print out data[0] for instance it prints out my ten 0s and nothing else, if I print data[1] it gives me another ten 0s, and no first column. Just as expected.

Comment: Can you post part of 'test.txt'?

Comment: Does each row of your .txt file have the same number of values?

Comment: Updated to include some of the sample data, and yes all rows have the same number of values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much mucking around I think that it's a strange bug or the like, possibly in numpy.

This entire code is similar to other bits, all defined inside of functions, making the data variables local. If I make the load function and all other bits inside this function use some other array name instead of the data variable name then it produces the expected results. I've double checked and there's no global to override it anyways, so unsure why it's happening. Must be a fringe case.

It also works if I just break out that one function into a completely separate file and run that code alone.

So in short, anyone else having this or a similar odd issue, try using another array variable name that you haven't used at all, and it might just go away.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I am quite sure there is no bug in numpy as what you are trying to do is a very, very basic thing.

Comment: Please take a look at the first example at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html and use StringIO in combination with loadtxt to paste a complete example with some of your data to your question. `from io import StringIO   # StringIO behaves like a file object
>>> c = StringIO("0 1\n2 3")
>>> np.loadtxt(c)
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.]])`

Comment: I'd agree Joe, but using a different array solved the issue. I'll investigat emore with a stringio object when I have some spare time. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me...

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('c:/temptemp/test.txt', usecols=range(1,11))
sdata = np.asfarray(np.sum(data,axis=1))
print(data)
print(sdata)
```

returns

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  8.]
```

Comment: Interesting, given that matches my code and file I'm stumped as to why this would be. It's like it's not ignoring that column for the sum command, but is when creating the data array...and when I sum on axis 0 it only has 10 columns it gives back. This is quite frustrating.